# match/filter/project nested fields from array in array in object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I need a little help , I attempt to extract some fields from nested array but yet struggeling , can somebody help?

Here is the example document:

```
[
{
_id: 1,
"_a": [
  {
    "_p": [
      {
        _pubId: {
          "CC": "EN"
        },
        _prid: "2",
        s: {
          c: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "4"
              },
              {
                secId: "5"
              }
            ]
          },
          d: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "6"
              },
              {
                secId: "7"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        _pubId: {
          "CC": "CZ"
        },
        _prid: "4",
        s: {
          c: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "8"
              },
              {
                secId: "9"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_p": [
      {
        _pubId: {
          "CC": "CZ"
        },
        _prid: "200",
        s: {
          c: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "4"
              },
              {
                secId: "5"
              }
            ]
          },
          d: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "6"
              },
              {
                secId: "7"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        _pubId: {
          "CC": "BG"
        },
        _prid: "4",
        s: {
          c: {
            text: [
              {
                secId: "8"
              },
              {
                secId: "9"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
]
```

And I need to extract all the "_a._p.s.[d|c].text.secId"  only for "_a._p._pubId.CC":"EN" , the output need to look as follow:

```
_prid , secId
{ _prid:2 , secId:4 }
{ _prid:2 , secId:5 }
{ _prid:2 , secId:6 }
{ _prid:2 , secId:7 }
```

[Example playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_MLJjPgycr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See Below** for updated aggregation pipeline based on comments from the OP.

This is pretty ugly, and needs to be tested on a larger collection, but this seems to output what you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$_a"},
  {"$unwind": "$_a._p"},
  {
    "$match": {
      "_a._p._pubId.CC": "EN"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_a._p._prid",
      "pridOut": {
        "$push": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": {"$objectToArray": "$_a._p.s"},
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value",
                {
                  "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$$this.v.text",
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", ["$$this"]]}
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "pridOut": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$pridOut",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {"$setUnion": ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "pridOut": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$pridOut",
          "as": "eachSecId",
          "in": {"$mergeObjects": [{"_prid": "$_id"}, "$$eachSecId"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$pridOut"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$pridOut"}
])
```

Output using your sample collection:

```json
[
  {"_prid": "2", "secId": "4"},
  {"_prid": "2", "secId": "5"},
  {"_prid": "2", "secId": "6"},
  {"_prid": "2", "secId": "7"}
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/034448VK8ZE).

#### This is Below :-)

Avoiding `"$unwind"` (until the end), here's another aggregation pipeline to produce the desired output.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_a._p._pubId.CC": "EN"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "output": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$_a._p",
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                }
              },
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "$cond": [
                      {"$eq": ["$$this._pubId.CC", "EN"]},
                      {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$this.s"},
                          "as": "s",
                          "in": {
                            "$map": {
                              "input": "$$s.v.text",
                              "as": "text",
                              "in": {
                                "$mergeObjects": [{"_prid": "$$this._prid"}, "$$text"]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      []
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$output"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$output"}
])
```

Try this on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_NA2F2PNwSA).

Comment: collection is pretty big for the 2x initial unwinds , but thanks , I was thinking for something map/reduce style to avoid the unwinds ...

Comment: @R2D2  I don't know what your collection looks like, but you may be able to lead with a `"$match"` to limit document processing.  I also don't know if identical `_prid` values are spread throughout the collection ... nor if they should be grouped together, nor if identical pairs (`"_prid"`, `"secId"`) should be uniqued, etc.

Comment: _prid are unique accross collecton , so group is not necessary , no duplicates expected , ~60% of docs are EN unfortunatelly

Comment: I just need to extract all secId per prid without grouping or checking for duolicates , but best to avoid unwind...

Comment: @R2D2  I updated the answer with another aggregation pipeline that you might find more useful.

Comment: This seems what I was looking for , thank you very much!